# How to contribute on ROS wiki page?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I have read Unit Test wiki provided [ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/gtest).
And I found a wrong link which have a 404 error.

How to edit this page?
It seem that it need some permission to edit the page.

Could you tell me a solution about this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300437/how-to-contribute-on-ros-wiki-page?/) by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2018-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After you have made an account on the ROS wiki, you can comment in this [thread](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/139), and the moderators will allow you to have edit access pretty quickly.

---

Originally posted by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) with karma: 711 on 2018-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on 2018-08-15**:
Thanks! BryceWilley